# cannot read property 'vertexNormals' of undefined

Tags: three.js

I used the example code from the three.js documentation page to load a .obj file with a .mtl and it keeps giving me the error cannot read property 'vertexNormals' of undefined.

The code is as follows:

```
// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

// load an obj / mtl resource pair
loader.load(
  // OBJ resource URL
  'models/farmhouse.obj',
  // MTL resource URL
  'models/farmhouse.mtl',
  // Function when both resources are loaded
  function ( object ) {
    scene.add( object );
  },
  // Function called when downloads progress
  function ( xhr ) {
    console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
  },
  // Function called when downloads error
  function ( xhr ) {
    console.log( 'An error happened' );
  }
);
```

Comment: Track it down with the debugger and identify the location of the error. You are not providing sufficient information for anyone to help you.

Comment: I spent alot of time tracking down with debuggers. Eventually found the solution, but I tried to find the smallest amount of code that introduced the error in order to post.  In reality this exact code producing that error means that an older three.js build is present and needs to be upgraded which can hopefully be helpful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This error is apparently a result of using the three.js mtl object loader with a older version of three.js build.  The issue was the three.js source from the package I was using wasn't compatible with the newer loaders that I was using from the documentation.

The solution was to add the newest build of three.js in place of the package's three.js build. (which did introduce other regressions to work through).  If you see this exact error from loading a model into a scene the three.js build is most likely outdated.